# Validation working in everything except IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have some basic form validation that works in chrome, mozilla, and safari, but when I run the page in IE explorer the validation throws my error for every variable that has get .value

The error triggers if the radio is not selected, but a dropdown option other than 'none' is checked

Any idea what I can do to make it work in IE

```
function isValid(){
    var ws = document.getElementById('ws').value;
    var wsrefill = document.getElementById('wsrefill').value;

    if (ws != "" && wsrefill == "None"){
        alert('Error');
        return false;
    }
```

below is the main parts of my html

```
<form onSubmit="return isValid();" name="order_form" id="order_form" method="post" >
<td colspan="2"><label><input type="radio" name="ws" id="ws" value="ws1" /> WS #1</label></td>
<td colspan="2"><label><input type="radio" name="ws" id="ws" value="ws2" /> WS #2</label></td>
<td colspan="4">
    Refills 
    <select name="wsrefill" id="wsrefill">
        <option value="None">Please Select</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="1 Year">1 year</option>
    </select>
</td>
<input type="submit" onClick="isValid();"/>
```

Comment: What version IE? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You've got two `id="ws"` inputs... that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Can you end your form element at the end? I do not see </form>

Comment: The form is ended that way, the 2 ws inputs are radios so selecting one unchecks the other. And its being tested on ie8

Comment: I just dont kbow why it works in everything but IE it does the opposite.

Comment: That's fine, but even radio inputs need unique id's.  Grouping occurs through the `name` property

Comment: it works the same for me in IE and in Chrome. Maybe you should explain better what is not working and what it needs to do

Comment: Yea the one thing i told the designer not to do, the bad part is it is this way in over 109 pages with 20 instances of it. Assuming i could change the id then i could just get the .checked value

Comment: The issue has something to do with the .value for ws, or in the ws != "" that is specific to ie